# How to fix runtime error of while loops?

Tags: java, while-loop, branch

the code show no error in the compiler but when the code run and the loops met the requirement it keep print out nonstop message here the picture http://i62.tinypic.com/23if4uv.png

also here is the code that i  use:

```
Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
int numbg = (int) (100*Math.random())+1;
String one = "That was lucky!";
String twofour="That was amazing!";
String fivesix= "That was good.";
String seven= "That was okay";
String enine = "That was not versy good";
String tm= "That just insn't your game";
System.out.println("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
int numbu = keyb.nextInt();
int wrong = 0;
while (numbg != numbu) {
    if  (numbu < numbg) {
        System.out.println("Your guess too low. Try again. ");
        wrong++;
        System.out.println("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
        numbu=keyb.nextInt();
    }
    else if (numbu > numbg && numbu <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Your guess too high. Try again.");
        wrong++;
        System.out.println("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
        numbu=keyb.nextInt();
    }
    else if (numbu > 100) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is out of range. Pick a number betwen 1 and 100");
        numbu=keyb.nextInt();
    }
    while (numbg == numbu) {
        if (wrong >= 1) {
            System.out.println(one);
        }
        else if (wrong >= 2 && wrong <= 4) {
            System.out.println(twofour);
        }
        else if (wrong >= 5 && wrong <= 6){
            System.out.println(fivesix);
        }
        else if (wrong == 7) {
            System.out.println(seven);
        }
        else if (wrong >=8 && wrong <= 9){
            System.out.println(enine);
        }
        else if (wrong >= 10) {
            System.out.println(tm);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using the debugger for this problem

Comment: Once you enter the `while (numbg==numbu)` loop, you'll never get out of it because neither `numbg` nor `numbu` are changed. So no wonder the loop doesn't terminate. Try to set something like `numbg = 0; numbu = 1` at the end of the scope of the loop, then check if you're still having the same problem.

Comment: @Mr.Yetti thank now i had fixed by changing delete that and start with branching

Answer (score 0):

The while loop that you have will never terminate since the requirements will always be met. I would recommend just using an if statement so it will only check once and if it meets the requirements it will only say the string once. Also, you should change all the if and if else statements that were in the while loop that should be changed to (wrong <= number) instead of >= because that condition will always be true since that means if you took number OR MORE guesses to find it instead of that number OR LESS.

Comment: ... and fix the first if statement.

Comment: if (wrong >=1) will always be true before any of the other else conditions.

Comment: Oh yes, along with all the other if statements there, Ill fix it

Comment: ummm sorry if i am wrong because i'm just beginner. what if i change the "int numbu" equal to 0 instead of scanning from user also delete the second loop and make the if statement stay out from the loop it should work right? and yes i had changed the wrong>=1 to ==1 instead.

Comment: You want to keep numb as a scanner otherwise how would you  get a guess from the user? Also, make not just wrong==1 but all of them such as wrong==2. One more thing, if you make if wrong==1 and nothing if they get 0 wrong, nothing will be printed out so you might want to use wrong<=1